# Checking interweaving strings in pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, mapreduce, list-comprehension

I have a problem for checking the interweaving strings. So, I have 3 strings and I need to check whether the third string can be formed by interweaving the first two strings.

To simplify, interweaving strings means to merge them by alternating their letters without any specific  pattern.

For example: `"abc"` and `"123"` are two strings and possible interweaving can be `"abc123"` or `"a1b2c3"` or `"ab1c23"` etc mixing them without any pattern but following order sequence.

another example, for false case:

```
str1 = "aabcc", 
str2 = "dbbca", 
str3 = "aadbbbaccc"  # This is false case, where str3 is not interweaving from str1 and str2
```

**what i have tried:**

I have tried below solution which is working for me. returning `True` if string `c` is interweaving of string `a` and `b` else returning `False`

```
def weavingstring(a,b,c):
    for i in c:
        if len(a)>0:
            if i == a[0]:
                a=a[1:]
        if len(b)>0:
            if i == b[0]:
                b=b[1:]
    if len(a) > 0 or len(b) > 0:
        return False
    return True
            

print(weavingstring("abc", "def", "abcdef"))  # True here
print(weavingstring("aabcc", "dbbca", "aadbbbaccc"))  # False here
```

**What i want**

I have the normal solution, I wanted to know if there is any pythonic way of doing this by using `list comprehension`, `map`, `filter`, `reduce` or `lambda functions` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach of using the **lru_cache** with ***lambda*** to speed things up:

```
from functools import lru_cache
class Solution:
    def isInterleave(self, s1: str, s2: str, s3: str) -> bool:
        return (memo:=lru_cache()
            ( lambda i=0, j=0, k=0:
                (i, j, k) == (len(s1), len(s2), len(s3))
                or ( i < len(s1) and k < len(s3) and s1[i] == s3[k] and memo( i+1, j, k+1 ) )
                or ( j < len(s2) and k < len(s3) and s2[j] == s3[k] and memo( i, j+1, k+1 ) ) )
        )()
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, any documentation link for `lru_cache` ?

Comment: Check out the official doc. - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Comment: I thought you prefer one of these methods - map, filter, reduce, **lambda** ...?

Comment: Yes, I prefer these. Thank you for the doc link.

Answer (score 1):

May I interest you in a simple recursive solution?

```py
def weaving(a: str, b: str, res: str) -> bool:
    if not a: return b == res
    if not b: return a == res
    if not res: return False
    if res[0] == a[0]:
        return weaving(a[1:], b, res[1:])
    elif res[0] == b[0]:
        return weaving(a, b[1:], res[1:])
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use regexes.

```py
import re
def iswoven(first, second, test):
    return all((re.search(r'.*'.join(x), test) for x in (first, second)))


>>> iswoven('abc', '123', 'a1b2c23')
True
>>> iswoven('abc', '123', 'a1b223')
False
```

This will check that the test string matches both 'a.*b.*c' and '1.*2.*3' and return the result.

Depending on the length of your strings, this could end up trying to match on some pretty hairy regexes, so buyer beware.

Comment: This won't work - try this example: print(iswoven('abcd', 'ABBCCDE', 'abABcBCCcDEd'))  # True?  <-- should it be False?

Comment: Based on OP's initial post and examples I took the criteria for an "interwoven string" to be *String 3 contains every letter from strings 1 and 2 in the same order they appeared, possibly interspersed.* However, OP did not indicate whether a string fitting the above criteria _that also contained other characters which appeared in neither strings 1 or 2_ should be considered true or false. Based on the accepted answer, I believe the intent of the OP was to specify a criteria like *String 3 contains ONLY letters from strings 1 and 2 in the same order they appeared, possibly interspersed.*